# Why is the potential electrical energy defined as the negative of the work integral, using couloumbs law to represent the force?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

I saw many questions formulated more or less with the same words, but what I am not understanding here is different.

The Coulomb law describe a force in a charge by others charges in the environment, but it not necessarily, and as far as I know, it really isn't the case for charges in movement(the relativists effects are noticeable in this situation), hence the Coulomb law is valid to inertially static corpses, so why here upon we use the Coulomb law (static description) to define the electrical potential - both energetic or not - that are associated with an idea of movement?

I expect to did not be confuse, thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok, I gotta ask - what are "inertially static corpses"?

Comment: oh sorry, I wanted to mean a particle, a body, whose in the adopted inertial frame of reference, is static, its position does not change with time.

Comment: I still far from any formal conclusion, but I was just remembering that the corrections are given in terms of magnetical field, once it force is perpendicular to the velocity its work isn't noticeable, hence upon it seems to be equivalent mathematically at least, but not complete as something carrying a physical sense...